# Среда разработки на C# для Linux

Tags: c#, linux

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите среду разработки на C# для linux (например, как на Windows - Visual Studio).

Answer (score 10):

Думаю это самая известная среда разработки: [MonoDevelop](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Answer (score 1):

QT Creator, KDevelop, Eclipse